# myetherwallet script dont run ng-init when there is a Var Data = {...} in the script

Tags: angularjs

I am modifying the open source code of `myetherwallet` to create a wallet in the background with the user interface and also to do the ETH transfer in the background when user initiates a transfer.

I manage to modify the code to generate wallet and store the address and private key. However, I am stuck in the initiating the `generate transaction` where it creates the signed transaction code for me to send to etherscan API to complete the transaction.

Currently, it generates the code by manually clicking on the button but I want it to auto initialise using `ng-init` and it's not working.

Below is the code in the html.

```
<a ng-init="generateTxTR()">Generate Transaction</a>
```

{{signedTx}}

The code in the etherwallet-master.js is as below.

```
$scope.generateTxTR = function () {       
var txData = {  
 to: $scope.tx.to,  
    value: '0.4',
    unit: $scope.tx.unit,
    gasLimit: $scope.tx.gasLimit,
    data: $scope.tx.data,
    from: $scope.wallet.getAddressString(),
    privKey: $scope.wallet.privKey ? $scope.wallet.getPrivateKeyString() : ''
};
txData.gasPrice = $scope.tx.gasPrice ? '0x' + new BigNumber($scope.tx.gasPrice).toString(16) : null;
$scope.generateTxTRJ();

};

$scope.generateTxTRJ = function (txData) {

    var genTxWithInfo = function genTxWithInfo(data) {
        var rawTx = {
            nonce: ethFuncs.sanitizeHex(data.nonce),
            gasPrice: data.isOffline ? ethFuncs.sanitizeHex(data.gasprice) : ethFuncs.sanitizeHex(ethFuncs.addTinyMoreToGas(data.gasprice)),
            gasLimit: ethFuncs.sanitizeHex(ethFuncs.decimalToHex(txData.gasLimit)),
            to: ethFuncs.sanitizeHex(txData.to),
            value: ethFuncs.sanitizeHex(ethFuncs.decimalToHex(etherUnits.toWei(txData.value, txData.unit))),
            data: ethFuncs.sanitizeHex(txData.data)
        }; 
            var eTx = new ethUtil.Tx(rawTx);
            eTx.sign(new Buffer(txData.privKey, 'hex'));
            rawTx.rawTx = JSON.stringify(rawTx);
            rawTx.signedTx = '0x' + eTx.serialize().toString('hex');
            rawTx.isError = false;
            $scope.rawTx = rawTx.rawTx;
            $scope.signedTx = rawTx.signedTx;
            if (!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply();
    };

            ajaxReq.getTransactionData(txData.from, function (data) 
            {
                data = data.data;
                data.isOffline = txData.isOffline ? txData.isOffline : false;
                genTxWithInfo(data);

            });

  };
```

Please help or please share if you have done any code using myetherwallet to generate wallet and perform the transfer in the background.

Regards
Thomas

Comment: There is no need to use ng-init just fire the function after it's defined in the controller `$scope.generateTxTR()`  The controller instance gets recreated every time it's needed for the view... ng-init is meant to allow you to alias special properties of ng-repeat or in some cases to inject some data from the server side though this is not a great use case IMO

Comment: Noted and thank you. How do can I send data retrieve from database via ASP Classic to Angujarjs. In javascript we can just use something like  var uid = '<%=session("uid")%>';. Please advise

Comment: For those kinds of things you could use ng-init (I've seen it done and the docs consider it a valid use case) personally I like to just have the backend write a value into a `angular.value('uid', <%=session("uid")%>);` then you can inject that value into any controller or wherever you need it by just passing uid into the function defining the controller/service/whatever you need to use it for `angular.constant` might make more sense for values that will never change too.

Comment: @shaunhusain thank you sir. I manage to find a easy way by defining it in the javavasacript and than read it from the angularjs.